# Displaying prime number using for loop in python.The output is repeating

Tags: python, loops, primes

Why is output repeating?

```
lower = int(input("enter lower interval: "))
upper = int(input("enter upper interval: "))
for num in range(lower,upper):
    if num>1:
        for i in range(2,num):
            if (num % i)  == 0:
                break
            
            else:
                print(num)
```

Output:

```
enter lower interval: 2
enter upper interval: 15
3
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
9
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the else statement for the for loop, not the if statement

```
upper = int(input("enter upper interval: "))
for num in range(lower,upper):
    if num>1:
        for i in range(2,num):
            if (num % i)  == 0:
                break
            
        else:
            print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

It repeats because of having there are multiple numbers that can not divide that number in the given range.
Try this hope will work:

```
lower = int(input("enter lower interval: "))
upper = int(input("enter upper interval: "))
for num in range(lower,upper):
  is_prime = True
  if num > 1:
     for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            is_prime = False            
  if is_prime == True:
    print(num)
```

I have checked if it pass the condition of `if (num % i) == 0:` then the number is not Prime